# What's wrong? PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in

Tags: php

Me and my mate we're trying to solve this for over 1.5 hours, we are still getting the same and tried almost everything we could.

Could anyone help us do that?

This is error what we're getting:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in
```

And this is the code (line) it's happening on:

`if(!isset($_POST['name'])) {echo"Please fill in a valid username"} else {$ok="$ok+1"}`

It's PHP.

If anyone wants the full code here it is:

```
$ok=0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(!isset($_POST['name'])) {echo"Please fill in a valid username"} else {$ok="$ok+1"}
if(!isset($_POST['pass'])) {echo"Please fill in a valid password"} else {$ok="$ok+1"}

if($ok==2){
switch($_POST['name'],$_POST['pass']){
    case "FORAEROND","FORAEROND2":


    THIS IS THE TEXT THAT WILL SHOW IF USERNAME IS 'FORAEROND' AND PASSWROD IS 'FORAEROND2'


    break;



    /*case "FORAEROND5","FORAEROND6";        KEEP FOR LATER

    THIS IS THE TEXT THAT WILL SHOW IF USERNAME IS 'FORAEROND5' AND PASSWROD IS 'FORAEROND6'


    break;
    */

    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who will help. :)

EDIT:

We apologize to everyone, it was really stupid, somehow we deleted or forgot ';' behind the codes, this is really stupid and awkward.

Comment: **else {$ok="$ok+1"}** add **;**  **else { $ok="$ok+1" ; }**

Comment: you forgot to add ; (semicolon) after echo. add semicolon and your error gets solved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You missed `;`. Each statement must ends up with a semicolon in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

You missed **Semicolumn(;)**

Replace

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'])) {echo"Please fill in a valid username"} else {$ok="$ok+1"}
```

with

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'])) {echo"Please fill in a valid username"; } else {$ok="$ok+1"; }
```

Comment: In my case I had an open  brace *(* that I had forgotten to close with a *)* closing brace.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ok="$ok+1"
```

you forgot a semicolon here, it should be:

```
$ok="$ok+1";
```

same goes for the others